# How does an array in C# gets derived from System.Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

We know how to define array like below but how does it gets derived from `System.Array`?

```
int[] intArray = new int[] { 2, 4, 7 };
```

The above example is a simple `int` array but imagine I have `Student` class and I make an array of students, that will still get derived from `System.Array`.

Is the above code declaration some kind of shortcut for a fully qualified declaration?

Comment: Using a type and defining that type are two very different things.  You have not defined any types in the code shown.

Answer (score 3):

> **The System.Array type**
>
> The type System.Array is the abstract base type of all array types. An
> implicit reference conversion (Implicit reference conversions) exists
> from any array type to System.Array, and an explicit reference
> conversion (Explicit reference conversions) exists from System.Array
> to any array type. Note that System.Array is not itself an array_type.
> Rather, it is a class_type from which all array_types are derived.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/arrays#the-systemarray-type

> Is the above code declaration some kind of shortcut for a fully qualified declaration?

No.  It's baked into the language that you declare array types by adding `[]` to other types.  Generics didn't exist in the language initially or `int[]` might have been shorthand for `Array<int>` or somesuch.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the features in C# are part of the language and are converted into the proper types or abstractions of types in the compile step. int, itself, is Int32 in the framework. VB.NET is even more rife with VB-ish shortcuts.

REMOVED link from wrong question. May edit again later.

Comment: This isn't syntax sugar; the .NET runtime supports arrays specially in this way as well (see ECMA-335 II.14). And I'm not sure what that link you posted has to do with arrays specifically? It looks like it's about extracting images from PDFs, not about the way the runtime treats arrays.

Comment: The C# language supports things like int[], string[], etc. and converts them in the C# compiler to the correct underlying type. I did not suggest this is syntactical sugar. It is just a compiler step as it creates IL. VB has some syntax that is converted as well. 

Instantiating with using also works a lot like a try ... finally in the compiler to ensure the Dispose() is called. Also not magic, just compilation.

Other than messing up the link, I am trying to figure what you disagree with. Maybe something I did not learn in my 20 years at this? If so, more than happy to learn.

Comment: I disagreed mostly with your link, since it seemed like the incorrect one, and I suspected it might have been spam. I have rescinded my downvote. I still feel "Many of the features in C# are part of the language and are converted into the proper types or abstractions of types in the compile step" at least *implies* some form of syntactic sugar is used for arrays, but I can see that might not have been your intention.